# Dynamic Task scheduler - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a Task Scheduler whose data comes from a table, it has time-frequency when it should be run and other data used for executing the task.

Now, The time-frequency is stored as day, week, a month which equates to `daily(), weekly(), monthly()` So I do something like this to modify the data and store it as a string.

```php
public function reportScheduler () {

    $allActiveScheduler = QaMetricsSchedule::selectRaw(
        ......
        'schedule_type as `schedule_type`,'.
        'schedule_time as `schedule_time`')
        ->where('status','=',1)
        ->get();

    if(count($allActiveScheduler) > 0){
        $allActiveScheduler = $allActiveScheduler->toArray();

        foreach ($allActiveScheduler as &$scheduler){

            $scheduler['schedule_type'] = 'everyMinute';
            if($scheduler->schedule_type === 'week'){
                $scheduler->schedule_type = "weeklyOn(1, '".$scheduler->schedule_time.":00')";
            }
            if($scheduler->schedule_type === 'month'){
                $scheduler->schedule_type = "monthlyOn(1, '".$scheduler->schedule_time.":00')";
            }
            if($scheduler->schedule_type === 'day'){
                $scheduler->schedule_type = "dailyAt('".$scheduler->schedule_time.":00')";
            }

        }
        return $allActiveScheduler;
    }
    return [];
}
```

And I run a for loop inside the `schedule` method to generate the task scheduler like so

```php
$allReportScheduler = self::reportScheduler();

foreach ($allReportScheduler as $reportScheduler) {
    $schedule->call(function () use ($reportScheduler){
        \Log::info('================ tableID->'.$reportScheduler['id']);
    })->{$reportScheduler['schedule_type']()};
}
```

The error is here `->{$reportScheduler['schedule_type']()};` not able to call string as a function.

> Call to undefined function everyMinute()

Can we not do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code:
The parenthesis braces should be placed outside the curly braces

```
->{$reportScheduler['schedule_type']}();
```